# Database master-detail relationship - How to prevent entering non existent value to master table?

Tags: database, delphi

In a master detail relationship

```
procedure TDataModule.TABLE1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
    if TABLE1.FieldByName('UNIT_ID').AsString <> '' then
    begin
        QUERY1.Close;
        QUERY1.SQL.Clear;

        QUERY1.SQL.Text:= 'select * from TABLE2 where UNIT_ID = ' +
        TABLE1.FieldByName('UNIT_ID').AsString;

        QUERY1.Open;
    end;
```

How can I make sure that when editing (and then saving) the `QUERY1` results someone does not enter the nonexistent `UNIT_ID`?

I want the `UNIT_ID` to be able to get changed, but I want to make sure someone does not enter `UNIT_ID` that does not exist.

Comment: Which database are you using? If it supports relations you can use foreign key otherwise beforepost event of QUERY1 can be used.

Comment: don't use SQL text splicing, sve yourself and server some work and use parameters. http://bobby-tables.com/delphi.html

Comment: why cannot you just put Table1 data source into query1 and pull both as one request with LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: look documentation about `TDataSet.IsEmpty` function

Comment: Querying some data with an ID currently selected in main table could be done automatically by configuring master-detail relation between Table1 and Query1. All you will have to do is just check Query1 for emptiness.

Comment: @Fr0sT, OP wants to edit/change ID of detail table (foreign key), but still match an existing master ID.

Answer (score 0):

AfterScroll is not right event use beforepost instead in this way:

```
procedure TDataModule.TABLE1BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
    if TABLE1.FieldByName('UNIT_ID').AsString <> '' then
    begin
        QUERY1.Close;
        QUERY1.SQL.Text:= 'select UNIT_ID from TABLE2 where UNIT_ID = ' +
            TABLE1.FieldByName('UNIT_ID').AsString;
        QUERY1.Open;
        if QUERY1.REcordcount=0 then ABORT; //so if there not a such
                                            // unit_id just don't save it
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `.RecordCount` is poor option for SQL sources - on some it would return -1 always, on others it would download half the database - gigabytes maybe - to the client computer, before would calculate the number.  For yes/no query there is a function `TDataset.IsEmpty`

Comment: @Arioch'The: "it would download half the database" - you made a similar comment to my since-deleted answer.  I'm not arguing, but I don't follow, since the query is contrained by the UNIT_ID value and in any event the OP seems to want to retrieve those rows if they *do* match.  Personally, I would be tempted to do a "select count(*) " separately from opening QUERY1, but anyway ...

Comment: Even in his case there is no directwarranty that there would be a single row for given id.

Comment: However the intention of StackOverf,low is to be a general FAQ, so that users would find answers here for years after they would be posted. Someone later, with different query would come here, and would learn to use RecordCount on any query even if it would return billions of records. You did not specified that your answer has dangers and limitations, so it is generic suggestion. And a risky one,  sadly.

Comment: Select count is also suboptimal. 1: it is an extra redundant network round-trip, sql parser/Optimizer work, etc. 2: on MVC servers like popular with Delphi Interbase/firebird this alone might be a slow and expensive request. 3: this value may change in between your first and second query. All in all, ask the system what you really want to know. You do not truly care how exactly many rows you can download, you only care if there is none of something, empty or not. Then ask just that, don't ask neither server nor client to enumerate all the rows of you are only interested in the first one

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wanted.